# How is the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M \mid x; R)$ defined in Hatcher's book AT?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

> [image]

This is on page 236 from *Algebraic Topology* by Hatcher, but I don't see where this map is defined before this statement.

How is the map $H_n(M;R) \to H_n(M \mid x; R)$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homology of pairs is covariant. In particular, the map of pairs $(M, \varnothing) \to (M, M-\{x\})$ (which is just the identity) induces a map $$H_n(M;R) = H_n(M,\varnothing;R) \to H_n(M, M-\{x\};R) = H_n(M\mid x;R).$$ This is the map in question.